# JQuery - Links inside divs not calling ajax, using Sortable and Flip

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, hyperlink

Problem is links or forms inside the divs aren't working.  Not at all sure what the problem is, and would appreciate a hand.

Its using both sortable and a card flip.

Click the fiddle link for the full code.

Some of the code:

```
<a href="#" id="delete">This Link Works</a>

<ul id="sortable">
    <div id="item-1" class="flip">
        <li id="item-1" class="ui-state-default">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="face front">
                    <div id="container_1">1
                    <P>Click to flip<BR>Drag to sort
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="face back">
                    <div>
                        <a href="#" id="delete">These Link Don't Work</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

The javascript:

```
  $(function () {
      $("#sortable").sortable();
      $("#sortable").disableSelection();
  });

  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.flip').click(function () {
          $(this).find('.card').addClass('flipped').mouseleave(function () {
              $(this).removeClass('flipped');
          });
          return false;
      });
  });

  $("#delete").click(function () {
      alert('Yup');
  });
```

[Fiddle] http://jsfiddle.net/FredSmith/kq03mx9L/14/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID's are unique - change those to class bindings

```
<a href="#" class="delete">
```

and

```
$(".delete").click(function () {
      alert('Yup');
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kq03mx9L/15/

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple links with the same ID. The jQuery gets confused. If you want several links to have the same functionality, use a CSS Class instead. :)